# How to open bag with blender!

Tags: modeling

I modeled this foil bag for the company i work for. Im trying to figure out how to make an "opened" comp. I try but it splits as i only want to give the appearance that its open. 
But it just splits. Heres the link to the file 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not hard at all, after looking at the downloaded file just merge the vertices on the outsides of the two parts. Then just use a shapekey to model the open bag version using proportional editing. Use the shapekey to get the open/closed bag version. You could animate it very easily as well if you want.

Comment: can you show me an example?